# How to find text in json array

Tags: node.js, json

Im making a game and one of its functions is to join/create private rooms. Private rooms are generated randomly, but before generating a room, I want to try to be sure that the room id don't exists.

```
var rooms = {
  'ROOM ID GENERATED RANDOMLY':
    Room {
     id: 'ROOM ID GENERATED RANDOMLY',
     players: [],
     gameState: 'WAITING',
     currentCard: 'g:2',
     currentPlayerIndex: NaN,
     currentDirection: 1,
     cardsStack: [] },

  'ROOM ID GENERATED RANDOMLY':
    Room {
     id: 'ROOM ID GENERATED RANDOMLY',
     players: [ [Player] ],
     gameState: 'WAITING',
     currentCard: 'g:2',
     currentPlayerIndex: 0,
     currentDirection: 1,
     cardsStack: [] },

   ...
}
```

Already tried

```
        var SEARCH = 'x';
        for (var i=0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
            console.log(rooms[i])
            if (rooms[i].Room.id === SEARCH) {
                return rooms[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: what doesn't work about what you tried? What error do you get when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
function roomIdIsUnique (newKey) {
    var roomKeys = Object.keys(rooms);

    for (const key of roomKeys) {
        if (key === newKey) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

var rooms = { /* Room objects */ }
var newRoomKey = /* Generate new room key code */

if (roomIdIsUnique(newRoomKey)) {
    /* Continue */
} else {
    /* Do something else */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty vague, but I'll do my best to answer it.

You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array containing the keys, and then run the `Array#indexOf` function on that array. It will return `-1` if the key is not in the array, else it will return the index

```
var rooms = { "key1": { property: "123" }, "key2": { property: "abc" } }
if(Object.keys(rooms).indexOf(SEARCH) != -1) {
    alert("Room id exists");
} else {
    alert("Room does not exist");
}
```